# How do I animate origin?

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, core-animation

I want to animate the position of a view based on the value of its top left point (the origin). I've tried both

```
CGPoint myPosition = CGPointMake(0, 500);
CABasicAnimation *yAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"frameOrigin"];
yAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:myPosition];
```

and

```
CGPoint myPosition = CGPointMake(0, 500);
CABasicAnimation *yAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"origin"];
yAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:myPosition];
```

and nothing works. How can I animate this property correctly?

Comment: frameOrigin is a property on NSView. Since you are using iOS it doesn't exist, UIView doesn't have a frameOrigin property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to animate the position of the view have a look at `UIViewAnimation` and using a block with it.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.7
        animations:^{
           //what you would like to animate
           myView.frame = CGRectMake(myView.frame.origin.x + 100,myView.frame.origin.y + 100, myView.frame.size.width, myView.frame.size.height);
        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
          //do something when the animation finishes
        }];
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are animating the frame instead of the center property? You are doing a calculation relative to the current value anyway.

Comment: No reason apart from the fact @wattson12 wanted to adjust the origin. Also sometimes you just want to put the origin somewhere instead of the centre property. You could calculate where you want the center in relation to the origin but just altering the frame is quicker

Comment: Is there a way I can set removedOnCompletion = YES on animateWithDuration?

Comment: Or just where i've put `//do something when the animation finished` add `[myView removeFromSuperview];`

Comment: I don't want to remove the view...I want to remove the animationKeys from the layer.

Comment: I was using animateWithDuration, but I wanted to try to chain some animation together using CAAnimationGroup. I've grown so frustrated with CAAnimationGroup...nothing has worked with it so I'm going back to animateWithDuration. This is why I've green checked this answer

Comment: I haven't done anything with CAAnimationGroup but with the chain animation stuff could you not start another animation when the previous one finishes?

Comment: You probably could, but there's supposed to be a built in process for chained animation (CAAnimationGroup). I can't get it to work and I'm sick of spending hours trying to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

There is no `origin` or `frameOrigin` key path on a `CALayer`, if you want to animate the position you will need to animate the `bounds` property

Comment: Don't you mean to animate the `position` property to animate the position? The bounds property will change the size

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist only if you change the size components of its rect, if you only change the origin it wont change size. but yes, position will work as well